# How to access index value of the option that has been selected by the user from the dropdownlist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the names of hotels in two ways. In first scenario, user can select any place from the dropdown list and after pressing "Go" button he can view the results.
Another scenario is to access the index value/number of the dropdown list option in the function "is checked()". How can I display the results of preferences by keeping the record of index value of my drop down list that has been selected by the user?

Below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <div class="header">

<h1> My manner</h1>
</div> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var dropdownlist;
       function is_checked(dropdownlist)
       {
        var Pool= document.getElementById('Pool').checked;
        var Gym= document.getElementById('Gym').checked;
        var Beach= document.getElementById('Beach').checked;
        var WiFi= document.getElementById('WiFi').checked;
        var Spa= document.getElementById('Spa').checked;


        if(Pool==false && Gym==false && Beach==false && WiFi==true && Spa==false)
          {
             window.open("www.google.com");
             return false;
          }

        else if(dropdownlist==1 && Pool==true && Gym==false && Beach==false && WiFi==false && Spa==false)
          {
              window.open("http://localhost/dubai%20rev/codeReviews.php");
              return true;
           }


       else if(dropdownlist==2 && Pool==true && Gym==false && Beach==false && WiFi==false && Spa==false)
          {
              window.open("http://localhost/london%20rev/code.php");
              return true;
           }

       }





     function goToNewPage(dropdownlist)
 {
 var url = dropdownlist.options[dropdownlist.selectedIndex].value;
 if (url != "")
 {
 window.open(url);
 }
 }
      </script>
</head>



<div class="menu">
<ul>

<li><a href="/signup">SIGN-UP</a></li>
<li><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="#n">HOME</a></li>



</ul>
</div>

<ul>

<div>
<ul class="rig columns-3" id="content"align="left" >
    <li>

    <h1>STAY</h1>
 <form name="dropdown">
 <select name="list" >
 <option selected>Select a place</option>
 <option value="http://localhost/dubai/codeDubai.php">Dubai</option>
 <option value="http://localhost/london/codeLondon.php">London</option>
 <option value="http://localhost/lahore/codeLahore.php">Lahore</option>
 <option value="http://localhost/newyork/Code.php">New York</option>
 <option value="http://localhost/canberra/code2.php">Canberra</option>
 </select>
 <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)">
</form>



    <br>
    <p2>Preferences</p2>
  <form  method="get" onsubmit="return is_checked(document.dropdown.list)">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Pool" id="Pool" checked="checked"> Pool <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Gym" id="Gym"> Gym <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Beach" id="Beach"> Beach <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="WiFi" id="WiFi" > WiFi <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Spa" id="Spa" > Spa<br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the overall intent isn't clear and the code is all over the place, but to point you in the right direction, you could start by first giving the drop-down list an `id` attribute:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="list">
```

^ This enables you to use **[The getElementById() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)**.

Then...

Use **[The Select object's selectedIndex property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)** to get the 0-based index of the selected item:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
```

And (if needed) use the **[Option object's value property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp)** to get the value of the selected option at the selected index:

```
var value = document.getElementById("mySelect").options[x].value;
```